# Pseudorandom Number Generator Using Uniform Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random, uniform-distribution

I am working out of *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis by John Rice* and ran into the following interesting problem I'm having trouble figuring out.

> Ch 2 (#65)
>
> How could random variables with the following density function be generated from a uniform random number generator?
>
> $$f(x) = \frac{1 + \alpha x}{2}, \quad -1 \leq x \leq 1,\quad -1 \leq \alpha \leq 1$$

So I believe I'm suppose to use the following fact to solve the problem

> Proposition D
>
> Let *U* be uniform on [0, 1], and let *X* = $F^{-1}$(*U*). Then the cdf of *X* is *F*.
>
> **Proof**
>
> $$P(X \leq x) = P(F^{-1}(U) \leq x) = P(U \leq F(x)) = F(x)$$

That is, we can use uniform random variables to generate other random variables that will have cdf *F*

So my goal should then be to find a cdf and it's inverse then give as input to the inverse the uniform random variable. I've included my attempt.

Given $f(x) = \frac{1 + \alpha x}{2}$

$$F(X) = \int_{-1}^{x} \frac{1 + \alpha t}{2} dt \; = \; \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\alpha x}{4} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{4}$$

$$4 \cdot F(X) - 2 + \alpha = 2x + \alpha x$$

$$F^{-1}(X) = \frac{4X - 2 + \alpha}{2 + \alpha}$$

So our random variable is, for example, T where

$$T = F^{-1}(U) = \frac{4U - 2 + \alpha}{2 + \alpha}$$

The answer in the back of the book is

$$X = [-1 + 2 \sqrt{1/4 - \alpha(1/2 - \alpha / 4 - U)}]/ \alpha$$

I'm not really sure where I went wrong. Any help?

Comment: I think I may have spotted a problem with my integration, I'll continue to try and work it out, but any other input is still welcome

Comment: Yes, the antiderivative should have a $t^2$ term.

Comment: Yes that was it, I worked it out. The devil's always in the details I guess

Comment: Slips of this kind are universal. The unfortunate thing is that sometimes they lead students who understand something perfectly well to doubt their understanding.

Comment: This is known as Inverse Transform Sampling. Its a good technique to generate random numbers from a given density, however its naive in a sense that the CDF must be calculated (which is not always possible or is too hard). The proof to why this works is here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

You should look into rejection sampling techniques to see an alternative way to generate random numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cdf appears to be wrong. When $-1\leq x\leq 1$,
\begin{align*}
F_X(x) &= \int_{-1}^{x} \frac{1 + \alpha t}{2} dt\\
&=\int_{-1}^x  \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}t\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[x+1]+\frac{\alpha}{4}[x^2-1]\\
\end{align*}
Other than that, your approach seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After completing the square I was able to solve it. I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @ApprenticeOfMathematics Don't worry. It was pointed out in the comments while I was writing the answer, but I didn't see it. I'm glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Demonstration in R with $\alpha = .2$ of answerbook result.

```
 alpha = .2;  m = 10^5;  u = runif(m)
 x = (-1 + 2*sqrt(1/4 + alpha*(1/2 + alpha/4 - u)))/alpha
 hist(x, col="wheat", prob=T)
 curve((1 + alpha*x)/2, -1, 1, lwd=2, col="blue", add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! It's awesome seeing simulations supporting the textbook result